# Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause' codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

hello friend  below is the query i am  executing and getting database error unknown column distance please help ..

```
$this->db->select("post.*,(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($cur_lat -abs(post.post_lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS($cur_lat * pi()/180) * COS(abs(post.post_lat) *  pi()/180)* POWER(SIN(($cur_long - post.post_long) *  pi()/180/2), 2) ))) as distance, source.*, user.firstname, user.lastname");
            $this->db->from('post');
            $this->db->join('user', 'user.id = post.cop_id');
            $this->db->join('source', 'post.source_id = source.id');
            $this->db->where('post.cop_id', $user_id);
            $this->db->where('post.post_lat !=', '');
            $this->db->where('post.post_long !=', '');
            if (!empty($radius)) {
                $this->db->where('distance <=', $radius);
            }
            if (!empty($source_array)) {
                $this->db->where_in('post.source_id', $source_array);
            }

            //$this->db->where('source.id !=', 4);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            echo $this->db->last_query(); 
            //  die();
            return $query->result();
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo $this->db->last_query();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the where() clause, you can use the having() clause which can see aliases.

```
$this->db->having('distance <=', $radius);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Alias field "distance" cannot be used in Where condition. That is why this error comes. You can use sub-query to do calculation and use its results to check in Where condition.

Comment: i have solved my probelem by using "having" clause instead of 'where'